# Get LDAP attribute value within liferay

Tags: active-directory, ldap, liferay

I am making custom Liferay developments in the class `com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPUtil`, especially the method that reads the LDAP users.
The LDAP in question is an Active Directory.

I want to access the attribute "userAccountControl" of a user:

```java
String userAccountControl = LDAPUtil.getAttributeValue(attrs,
          "userAccountControl ");
```

I always get an empty string when calling this, even if the user has a value for this attribute. I use JXplorer to make sure that I have some LDAP users with the attribute.

How to get the value of the LDAP attribute?

Comment: Do note that you will get an integer back via LDAP, and this is a bit mask for the various User Account Control settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the authentication identity of the connection has permission to read the value of the attribute.

Comment: Thank you sir. The ldap user/password in liferay is hidden, so I am searching with my client the correct values.

Comment: In fact, I already have a user/password to query JXplorer but It may be different than the one used in liferay.